# How to add array elements to the Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created a dictionary and need to pass the array elements to the dictionary as keys and "Num" will be the value of all the unique keys.Since I am new to Programming and Practicing the basics.Can anybody help me in doing this?.

```
public void InsertIntoDict(int[] arrayItem)
{
   Dictionary<int[],string> arrayDictionary = newDictionary<int[],string>();
   Console.WriteLine("dictionary items are");
   foreach (int item in arrayItem)
   {
      arrayDictionary.Add(item, "num");
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int[],string> i in arrayDictionary)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i.Value,i.Key);
    }
                   //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with this code? What do you mean the *value of all unique keys* - are the values of `arrayItem` not unique?

Comment: please share your data as well.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't intend to create a `Dictionary<int, string>`, not `Dictionary<int[],string>`?

Comment: Using an array as a Key is a bad idea.  Arrays use reference equality meaning that if you have two arrays with the same length and same int values in the same order the Dictionary is not going to see them as equal.  You could use a `Tuple` or the new value tuple instead assuming that you need a fixed number of values in your key.

Comment: You should return the dictionary as the functions result and set the functions result to some other dictionary variable to dont loose the result.

Comment: Why do you have array of int as key, when you effectivly only ever add a single number as key to your dictionary? Sounds like you need a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead.